# Pandas min_periods in time based window

Tags: python, pandas

I'm trying to use timestamp as window to process my data.

my data is like

```
Timestamp       A

8:17:11 AM      1
8:17:11 AM      2
8:17:12 AM      3
8:17:12 AM      4
8:17:13 AM      5 
8:17:13 AM      6
```

my code

```
df['test'] = df['A'].rolling('2s').sum()
```

where the window size is 2 seconds here, the ouput data before the first two seconds should be null

but my result is like

```
Timestamp       A    test

8:17:11 AM      1      1
8:17:11 AM      2      3
8:17:12 AM      3      6
8:17:12 AM      4      10
8:17:13 AM      5      12
8:17:13 AM      6      18
```

where result at 8:17:11 are shown

is there anyway to disable the feature that the result shows when the data size is smaller than window size?

I tried to use min_period, which in the documenatation says

> Minimum number of observations in window required to have a value  (otherwise result is NA).

but it seems doesn't work for time window

How should I solve this question?

Answer (score 0):

If you have index as `datetime` then use `min_period`:

```
df = df.rolling('2s', min_periods=2).sum()
```

for 9s period and starting summing for minimum 2 elements:

```
df = df.rolling('9s', min_periods=2).sum()
```

**Output:**

```
                        A
Timestamp                
2020-02-08 08:17:11   NaN
2020-02-08 08:17:11   3.0
2020-02-08 08:17:12   6.0
2020-02-08 08:17:12  10.0
2020-02-08 08:17:13  12.0
2020-02-08 08:17:13  18.0
```

Comment: I tried this again, I set min_periods to 10, but it gives null to first 9 rows, instead of first 9 seconds

Comment: @whtitefall you need to set `min_periods` to `2`

Comment: yeah i know set min_periods to 2 works for this example, but in reality I want to sepcify any time, and repeated timestamp is not always two... so It might have nine or eight timestamps like 08:17:11

Comment: @whtitefall instead of changing `min_periods` change number of seconds to `10s` wtis will count all rows within period of `10s` .`min_periods` is setting minimal numbers of rows that is needed to make sum.

Answer (score 0):

You can subtract the timestamp of the first index from the index and apply some rule whenever that result is smaller/larger than 0.

Answer (score 0):

Something like this should work:

```
import numpy as np
from datetime import timedelta
import pandas as pd
window = pd.Timedelta(timedelta(seconds=2))
df["test"] = df["A"].rolling(window).sum()
# get rid of non-complete window
df.loc[:df.index[0] + window, "test"] = np.nan
```